# How to generate grid matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to generate a matrix that contains (x,y) points of a given space.

```
xvalue = -15:0.25:20
yvalue = -20:0.25:25

for i = 1:141
    for j =1:181
        point1(i,j) = [xvalue(1,i) yvalue(1,j)];
    end
end
```

This code is giving an error. I'm new to matlab please help. I want the matrix to look like this

```
1  1


1  2

1  3
.

.
.
.
```

Error:

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch
```

Comment: what error is there?

Comment: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch. --> this the error

Comment: Thats because `point1(i,j)` is 1 value, while `[xvalue(1,i) yvalue(1,j)]` are 2 values. You can not put 2 values in 1

Comment: How to remove this error?

Comment: "How to remove this error?" By assignment only with the right dimensions. In your case by dropping one of the two values. Alternatively, inbuilt Matlab functions might also help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want is to use [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to generate a grid of coordinates, then reshape the coordinates so that it is a matrix of two columns:

```
xvalue = -15:0.25:20;
yvalue = -20:0.25:25;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xvalue, yvalue);
point1 = [X(:) Y(:)];
```

We first create the desired resolution in the `x` and `y` directions, then use `meshgrid` to generate a 2D grid of coordinates where each element `X(i,j)` and `Y(i,j)` together give you a unique `(x,y)` coordinate in a 2D Cartesian plane.  You then do `X(:)` and `Y(:)` to unroll each matrix into a column vector, then we stack these two column vectors into a single two column matrix.  The result would be each row providing a unique 2D Cartesian coordinate defined by the ranges of `x` and `y` you defined.

However, if you want to correct your code, what you need to do is pre-allocate your output matrix so that the number of rows is the total number of pairs required to generate your grid, which is simply the multiplication of the number of values in `xvalue` and `yvalue` and the number of columns being 2, then use a separate counter to iterate through each row of your output matrix and add each pair of values to each row:

```
% Your code
xvalue = -15:0.25:20;
yvalue = -20:0.25:25;

% Allocate matrix to store our coordinates
point1 = zeros(numel(xvalue)*numel(yvalue), 2);

% Initialize counter
count = 1;

% For each pair of values...
for i = 1:numel(xvalue)
    for j =1:numel(yvalue)
        % Add this to the right row of the output
        point1(count,:) = [xvalue(i) yvalue(j)];
        count = count + 1; % So we can move to the next row
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks mate! It helped a ton.

Comment: @papabiceps You're very welcome :) I'm just adding some more edits so you can see how to correct your current code.

Comment: @papabiceps I've added some more information on how to get your code working.  Thanks for the accept and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

A direct way  (and I think faster than  @rayryeng's suggest):

```
xvalue = -15:0.25:20;
yvalue = -20:0.25:25;
xymat(:,1)=kron(xvalue ,ones(1,length(yvalue)));
xymat(:,2)=repmat(yvalue',length(xvalue),1);
```

Comment: Interesting.  Actually, you are replicating what `meshgrid` is doing under the hood :).

Comment: BTW, it seems that speed is same for both methods.

Comment: It uses `kron` and `repmat` basically but the second parameter is matrix for `kron`... it's almost the same, but the point is that it does use `kron` and `repmat`!

Comment: Interesting, nice to know.  make sense, while Matlab likes vector-wise manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are achieving. You are assigning a 1X2 matrix each to a matrix, but its entries are supposed to be double. 
Maybe you can do it with declaring `point1` to be a [cell](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).

```
point1 =cell(141,181);
xvalue = -15:0.25:20;
yvalue = -20:0.25:25;

for i = 1:141
    for j =1:181
        point1{i,j} = [xvalue(1,i) yvalue(1,j)];
    end
end
```

If you intend a string, convert them to strings.

```
point1 =cell(141,181);
xvalue = -15:0.25:20;
yvalue = -20:0.25:25;

for i = 1:141
    for j =1:181
        point1{i,j} = [ num2str(xvalue(1,i)), ' ', num2str(yvalue(1,j)) ];
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, now I understand my mistake. My goal is to create a grid vector that consists of coordinates of a rectangular region of range of xvalue and yvalue. vector has to consist of x and y coordinates in each row.